# Splitting lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell I need to perform a function, whose declaration of types is as follows:

```
split ::[Integer] -> Maybe ([Integer],[Integer])
```

Let it work as follows:

```
split [1,2,3,4,5,15] = Just ([1,2,3,4,5],[15])
```

Because, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15

```
split [1,3,3,4,3] = Just ([1,3,3],[4,3])
```

Because, 1 + 3 + 3 = 7 = 4 + 3

```
split [1,5,7,8,0] = Nothing
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
split :: [Integer] -> ([Integer], [Integer])
split xs = (ys, zs)
 where
   ys <- subsequences xs,  ys isInfixOf xs, sum ys == sum zs
   zs == xs \\ ys
```

---

**Determines whether the list of positive integers xs can be divided into two parts (without rearranging its elements) with the same sum. If possible, its value is the pair formed by the two parts. If it's not, its value is Nothing.**
How can I do it?

Comment: No, it is an error

Comment: A function of type `[Integer] -> ([Integer], [Integer])` can't return `Nothing`. It would need to have the return type `Maybe` for that.

Comment: Yes, of course. I have forgotten it.

Comment: Why is the second example `[1,3,3],[4,3]` and not `[1,3,3],[3,4]`? Does the specification specifically talk about longest prefix and suffix with equal sums?

Comment: Because the elements have to be arranged in the same way as in the original list. @SebastianRedl

Comment: @mathandtic `[1,3,3],[3,4]` *is* the same order as the original list.

Comment: Yes, it is true, so in this case it could be 2 lists. @ גלעד ברקן

Comment: I have upload what I want in precisely way

Comment: @mathandtic I still don't think the instructions are clear. By "can be divided into two parts", I would think that all the elements of the original list have to be used, but your second example doesn't meet this criteria.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I have put a bad example

Comment: For this reason, I have changed it. @SebastianRedl

Comment: Ok, now the instructions are clear, but you haven't actually asked a question. You posted your attempt and said "it doesn't work", but that's not a question. And the question "how do I do this" is too broad. (Hint for solving it: make use of the built-in `splitAt` function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could also do is create a function that gives all possible splittings of a list:

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits xs = zipWith splitAt [1..(length xs)-1] $ repeat xs
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> splits [1,2,3,4,5,15]
[([1],[2,3,4,5,15]),([1,2],[3,4,5,15]),([1,2,3],[4,5,15]),([1,2,3,4],[5,15]),([1,2,3,4,5],[15])]
```

Then you could just use [`find`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:find) from `Data.List` to find the first pair of splitted lists that have equal sums:

```
import Data.List

splitSum :: [Integer] -> Maybe ([Integer], [Integer])
splitSum xs = find (\(x, y) -> sum x == sum y) $ splits xs
```

Which works as intended:

```
*Main> splitSum [1,2,3,4,5,15]
Just ([1,2,3,4,5],[15])
```

Since `find` returns `Maybe a`, the types automatically match up.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, since this is a learning exercise and you want hints, but if you want to use `subsequences` from `Data.List`, you could then remove each element of the subsequence you are checking from the original list with `\\`, to get the difference, and compare the sums.  You were on the right track, but you need to either find the first subsequence that works and return `Just (ys, zs)`, or else `Nothing`.

You can make the test for some given subsequence a predicate and search with `find`.

Comment: It doesn't homework, it is an exercise that I saw in a web for learning Haskell, but I can't know how to do it. So, I have asked in order to you could help to me. Sorry, it is unexplained.

Comment: My apologies.  Shouldn’t have jumped to conclusions.